# How can I give read access to User for users on a Customer Community licence?

Tags: lightning-web-components, permissions, security, customer-community

I have a lookup field called `Requested_By__c` which looks up to User. It is on a custom object called `Sample__c`. In my LWC (`sampleHelpInfo`) I am using `@wire` to get the sample record and the ID of the user in the `Requested_By__c` field. Then I am using `@wire` again to get the email address of that user.

sampleHelpInfo.js:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import SAMPLE_REQUESTED_BY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/GT_Samples__c.Requested_By__c'
import USER_EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email'

export default class SampleHelpInfo extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    sample;
    @track requestedById;
    @track requestedByEmail;
    @track user;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [SAMPLE_REQUESTED_BY_FIELD]})
        wiredSample({ error, data}) {
            if (data) {
                this.sample = data;
                this.error = undefined;
                this.requestedById = data.fields.Requested_By__c.value;
            } else if (error) {
                this.error = error;
                this.sample = undefined;
            }
        }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$requestedById', fields: [USER_EMAIL_FIELD]})
    wiredUser({ error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.user = data;
            this.requestedByEmail = data.fields.Email.value;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.user = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

sampleInfo.html:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <p>Please contact<a href="mailto:{requestedByEmail}"> {requestedByEmail}</a> for any requested sample amendments.</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

sampleHelpInfo.js-meta.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Sample Record Id" description="Gives the component the record id of the sample in context" default="{!recordId}"></property>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

My problem is that when logged in as a user on a customer community licence I get the following error on `wiredUser`:

```
status": 404,
    "body": {
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist",
        "statusCode": 404,
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND"
    },
    "headers": {}
```

Is this because customer community licence users don't have access to the User object? I can't see anywhere on the profile that I can assign read access to the user object. The user email address is returned as expected when I am logged in on my admin profile.

Comment: does this help? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_user_sharing.htm&type=5 or Sharing Rules?

Comment: wasn't able to solve my problem using this info but it's good to know. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a formula field on my Sample object rather than using the LWC controller to look to the user.